# Why does my computer overheat so easy?

Tags: laptop, battery, cooling

I have an HP DV5-1002nr, and when I had first gotten it, it overheated really easy. A few months later, it didnt overheat as often and eventually the problem just went away. My batter dies really fast so I ordered a new battery and finally got a new one a few weeks ago, and suddenly, my laptop is overheating like heck again. What is causing my laptop to overheat with the new battery? Could this wear out my battery faster (I was told they last a few year, I had to order this new one a few weeks more than 2 years after I got the first one).

My question is, why would a new battery affect how easily my laptop overheats?

Comment: 2 years is better than average for battery life these days, have you scanned your PC for malware lately? Free MBAM scanner...http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible that the relationship between getting a new battery and the computer starting to overheat is coincidental.  The most likely cause of overheating is clogged or dirty vents.  Try blowing compressed air through the vents (with the computer off and unplugged, just to be safe).  In some cases the vents are designed strangely or become too clogged, meaning the compressed air might not work.

Comment: or obstructed vents, e.g. by putting the laptop on a cushion or fluffy carpet.

Comment: It may be just coincidental, I just think its strange that my laptop overheated a lot when I first bought it, and it overheated less and less often, and suddenly I get a new battery and it overheats all of a sudden now.

Answer (score 1):

Open the process list, see if any processes consume > 50% of CPU constantly. Often the culprit is a flash clip; try closing open web pages with flash and see if it helps. Get rid of the CPU hog process.

Check that your OS correctly understands ACPI on your computer, so that it is able to lower power consumption when idling. E.g. in Device Manager check that there are no unrecognized components, and an ACPI controller is present somewhere in 'System devices'.

Maybe (but not very probably) it's the faulty disk that consumes unusually much electricity. Get a S.M.A.R.T. monitor tool (several free or limited-demo available) and check disk's temperature and health status.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, heat is a battery killer. 18 months to two years is a normal lifespan for a battery though.

You need to make sure the airflow in the laptop is good, as well as the fans. Have it looked at by a computer shop to make sure it's not something like heat paste on certain heatsinks that is causing the overheating. I've seen dust kill machines.